# Spring jdbc insert statement with sequence.nexval

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring and Postgres, and am trying to do an INSERT. The table `approvalsubmission` has a sequence called `approvalsubmission_ids`.

So I try use `nextval` to populate the `id` column. But I get an error.

**Question**

How do I need to construct the query?

I have the following query:

```
public void updateApprovalSubmission(String corporateTravelRequestUri, String approvalRequestId, byte[] approvalRequestXml, Date requestedDate) {
    String query = "INSERT INTO approvalsubmission(" +
            "id, approvalrequestid, conclusion, conclusionmessage, modifyable, resubmissionof, requesteddate, requested, conclusiondate, approvalrequestxml, escalationlevel) " +
            "VALUES (approvalsubmission_ids.nextval, :approvalrequestid, :conclusion, :conclusionmessage, :modifyable, :resubmissionof, :requesteddate, :requested, :conclusiondate, :approvalrequestxml, :escalationlevel);";
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("approvalrequestid", approvalRequestId);
    parameters.addValue("conclusion", null);
    parameters.addValue("conclusionmessage", null);
    parameters.addValue("modifyable", null);
    parameters.addValue("resubmissionof", null);
    parameters.addValue("requesteddate", requestedDate);
    parameters.addValue("requested", corporateTravelRequestUri);
    parameters.addValue("conclusiondate", null);
    parameters.addValue("approvalrequestxml", approvalRequestXml);
    parameters.addValue("escalationlevel", null);

    int noRowsUpdates = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(query, parameters);
    logger.info("updateApprovalSubmission: "+noRowsUpdates+" row updated for corporateTravelRequestUri: "+corporateTravelRequestUri+" and approvalRequestId: "+approvalRequestId);
}
```

It generates the following error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry
> for table "approvalsubmission_ids"

Comment: You should be calling nextval('approvalsubmission_ids').

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36782149/100836

Answer (score 0):

Another choice would be create those `id` columns using the PostgreSQL type `serial` (*or subtypes:* `smallserial`, `bigserial`).

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

In that way, you won't need to specify in your `insert` statement neither the column `id` nor its "related value", because database will manage that for you.